# Change displot bar colors to a specific color

Tags: python, seaborn, displot

I am struggling to change my displot bar colours.

I want to change the colour of the bars to the light blue colour on at the end of the palette (shown below).

[image]

I have tried this, but the colour seems to remain as a dark blue, which is not what I want.

```
sns.color_palette("light:b", as_cmap=True)
sns.displot(data=df, x="col_1", height=7, aspect=2.8, palette="light:b")
```

How do I change the colours to a specific colour in the palette?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just define your `custom colour palette`.

```
palette = ["#090364", "#091e75", "#093885", "#085396", "#086da6", 
           "#0888b7", "#08a2c7" ]

sns.set_style("whitegrid")
plot = sns.displot(....,palette=sns.color_palette(palette, len(palette)),...)
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution.